# Is it possible to obtain the key that triggered a function to be called if there was one?

Tags: key-bindings

Consider the following function and mapping.

```
function! GetInvoker()
    echom "I was invokeed by the key "
    echom <This_should_echo_F_or_G>
endfunction

map F :call GetInvoker()<CR>
map G :call GetInvoker()<CR>
```

How do I determine which key that the user actually typed from inside the function?

Comment: Simpler just to pass the mapped key as an arg to the function

Comment: Gotta agree with DBK. From the standpoint of the called function the input buffer when call occurs as part of a mapping is indistinguishable from a manual/direct call to the function, I believe. Unless there's some special internal `v:` variable or the like that I'm not aware of that contains this information it's likely impossible to determine.

Comment: not possible currently. There was some discussion about a new `v:variable` that allows that, but it has not been implemented yet.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Cool. Would it be something simple/granular like `v:caller_mapping` (e.g. mapped key(s) or null) or something broader (e.g. dict with various data about caller/callee state)? Or did it even get that far?

Comment: no it didn't get that far. I believe it was just a whishlist to allow something like that. That's actually quite an old wish, I remember I wished for that years ago when I started with Vim and the workaround to give the key as argument to the function (while ugly) works quite well. So I wouldn't bet on implementing it anytime soon.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Got it. Thanks for the details.

Answer (score 2):

You need to explicitly pass the key into the function; there's no built-in way to obtain that from Vim; this isn't a common use case. As plugins should only have a few keymappings, this approach should be fine. *Metaprogramming* (e.g. a `:for` loop) could be used to automatically define many mappings without duplicating all the information.

```
function! GetInvoker( key )
    echom "I was invokeed by the key "
    echom a:key
endfunction

map F :call GetInvoker('F')<CR>
map G :call GetInvoker('G')<CR>
```